# "KeyDown" event not triggered when typing with Vietnam language

Tags: xaml, uwp, textbox, uwp-xaml, keydown

I am developing and UWP app. I need to customize the "KeyDown" event of "TextBox" control.
"KeyDown" event not triggered when typing with Vietnam language but it works fine with English / Korean typing.

Do I need to add anything additional settings or change any properties?
Can anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

> "KeyDown” event not triggered when typing with Vietnam language

It is by design, enable the [Input Method Editor (IME)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/apps/hh967427(v=win.10)) and Text Services Framework (TSF) when your apps have users who require assistive technology to enter text in complex languages, like Japanese and Simplified Chinese. Apps do not receive this event when an **Input Method Editor (IME)** is enabled. The Input Method Editor (IME) [**handles all keyboard input**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.core.corewindow.keydown) and sets Handled to true.